# Sum only specific rows in a Tensorflow tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

I have a BERT model predicting a tensor containing the token embeddings/probabilities associated to each (subword) token. I would like to sum the vectors of only a few rows (the ones corresponding to  original untokenized input words), but I do not know how to accomplish this in a Keras custom layer.

Let's assume that Bert outputs a tensor with shape (10, 5), where each row corresponds to a Bert token. rows 4 and 5 coincide with an original untokenized word, and I would like to sum them and return the new vector with the rest of the original tensor (therefore a tensor with shape 9,5). How to accomplish this?

I tried to create a Variable tensor and use the `word_ids` method to know which rows of a tensor correspond to original untokenized words. However, I cannot use a for-loop on a Tensorflow tensor, and therefore I do not know how to tackle the issue.